# Как реализовать магазин через telebot

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Делаю магазин через telebot,столкнулся с проблемой. Допустим есть подкатегория товара и есть товар, подкатегории храню в базе данных и выгружаю для добавления кнопок, т.к. есть функция добавления и удаления подкатегорий, как сделать так, чтобы товар был привязан к определенным подкатегориям, я не могу добавить несколько товаров в одно строчку чтобы они были привязаны к определенной нужной категории. Как быть?

Comment: Добавить третью таблицу, которая будет хранить ключи товаров и подкатегорий

Comment: Не думаю, что вопрос касается [tag:python] и [tag:telebot]. Удалил эти метки. Верните, если я ошибся